# Mysql Create Table error

Tags: mysql, create-table

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts(

Contact_ID INT NOT NULL ,
User VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
User_ID INT( 15 ) ,
PRIMARY KEY ( Contact_ID ) ,
FOREIGN KEY ( User_ID ) REFERENCES Users( User_ID )
)
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
User_ID int(15),
PRIMARY KEY (Contact_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (User_ID) RE' at line 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply the length of the `VARCHAR` field, like `VARCHAR(64)`.

Comment: Yes it worked thank
but why ?
look at this link here please
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: The 64 means 64 characters can be stored in that field, you can freely change it.

Comment: Just what Erik said. Varchar fields require an explicit length, which becomes the maximum number of characters you can put in the field.

Comment: That link has nothing to do with `VARCHAR`.

Comment: @ErikEkman I mean to saay that on that page they are also not defining integer length.

Comment: The length of `INT` is optional since it is only about how many digits to display and not about storage length. `VARCHAR` is different though.